# regex issue on splitting a string

Tags: php, regex

having another short regex problem.

Basically I have a string like such:

`cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH`

I'm trying to get just the `WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS` from that string.

I'm trying something like this:

`preg_match('/[cn=.]+.*[^,.*]+$/', $info[0]['groupmembership'][0], $matches);`

`print_r($matches);`
Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH,ou=WM,ou=SWQ,o=HEALTH
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any simply delimited string, this is most easily done by splitting on the delimiters: first commas, then on the `=`:

```
$parts = explode(",", "cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH");
$cn = $parts[0];
list($component, $value) = explode($cn);
echo $value;
```

And if you really will only want the first part, you can shorten it with another `list()`:

```
list($cn) = explode(",", "cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH");
list($component, $value) = explode("=", $cn);
echo $value;
```

But if you really wish to do it with a regular expression, it should work as:

```
preg_match('/cn=([^,]+)/',  "cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH", $matches);
var_dump($matches);

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS"
  [1]=>
  string(26) "WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS"
}
```

`([^,]+)` matches everything up to the next `,` following `cn=`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I didn't want to do it with explode for my list of them :P

I have to wait 5 minutes, but until then, you may have my first born.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/cn=([^,]+)/", $string, $match); 
$match[1]; //WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS
```

Answer (score 1):

This matches everything after cn= until a comma appears.

```
preg_match('/cn=([^,]+)/i', 'cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH', $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS
    [1] => WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS
)
```

Answer (score 0):

pardon me for using PowerShell, but the RegEx should be the same, i think:

```
([Regex]::Matches("cn=WSG-AP-LO-COMMON-SITE-APPS,ou=ZFD,ou=SVC,ou=IGH", "cn=([^,]+)"))[0].Groups[1]
```